# Evaluating functions for different values of parameters

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

here it is my question.
I have a system of two equations in two variables, so I can get a solution. The issue is that those equations depend on three parameters, so my solution will depend on their values. How can I make Mathematica evaluating the solution for different values of the parameters?

Example: I want so find the solution of the following:

```
NSolve[x == (3 k + 6 m - 3 y)/(6 t) && y == (k + 2 t - 3 x + m)/(3 t), {x, y}]
```

Trivially, the solution depends on the values of m, t and k. Let's say each of them may assume any value in the interval [0,1]. I have already used Manipulate, just to get an insight:

```
Manipulate[NSolve[x == (3 k + 6 m - 3 y)/(6 t) &&  y == (k + 2 t - 3 x + m)/(3 t), {x, y}], {m, 0, 1}, {t, 0.1, 1}, {k, 0, 1}]
```

Of course, this is not a final solution. How can I solve the problem? 
P.s. if necessary, I can fix the value of t equal to 1. If so, how can I create a plot or a table of all the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function that takes the parameters,

```
s[k_,m_,t_] = {x, y} /. Solve[
    x == (3 k + 6 m - 3 y)/(6 t) && 
    y == (k + 2 t - 3 x + m)/(3 t), {x, y}][[1]]
```

where the `[[1]]` just drops one layer of `{curly braces}` (which is safe since your equations are linear).

Then you can plug numbers in for `k`, `m`, `t`:

```
Outer[s,(*k:*)Subdivide[0, 1, 2],(*m:*)Subdivide[0, 1, 3],(*t:*) Subdivide[0, 1, 4]]
```

which gives a table of shape `{3,4,5,2}` (the last 2 is for the `{x,y}` pair.  You can replace `Subdivide` with `Range` or whatever other function you like to generate numbers.  You can also

```
Table[s[k, m, t], {k, 0, 1, 1/2}, {m, 0, 1, 1/3}, {t, 0, 1, 1/4}]
```

to get the same result.

To plot at a fixed t you can do something like

```
witht[t_] :=  Flatten[Table[{{k, m}, s[k, m, t]}, 
                            {k, 0, 1, 0.01},
                            {m, 0, 1, 0.01}], 1]

ListVectorPlot[witht[1], FrameLabel -> {"k", "m"}]
```

which gives

[image: 2D stream plot]

You can plot in 3D too,

```
vectors = Flatten[Table[{
    {k, m, t}, 
    s[k, m, t]~Join~{0}
    }, 
    {k, 0, 1, 0.1}, {m, 0, 1, 0.1}, {t, 0, 1, 0.1}], 2]

ListVectorPlot3D[vectors, AxesLabel -> {"k", "m", "t"}]
```

(I turned down the number of points.  The `~Join~{0}` is required because ListVectorPlot3D needs a 3D vector to plot.

[image: 3D vector plot]

You can also animate the 2D plot, using `Animate` (which is like `Manipulate`),

```
Animate[ListVectorPlot[witht[t], FrameLabel -> {"k", "m"}], {t, 0, 1, 0.01}]
```

[image: animation changing t]

Comment: As far as plotting goes... you have a 3-dimensional input space and a 2-dimensional output, so how to plot is not obvious.

Comment: Wow, that is a very good answer! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure!  Feel free to give it an upvote.  After a day or two you can "Accept" the most helpful answer---waiting some time lets other people respond too.

Comment: Of course I have already upvoted, just my reputation is too low so it is not shown.
Just to be sure,  basically this code firstly creates a function called s which runs the command Solve for given values of k, m and t, right? From that part, I just don't understand this -> {x, y} /. and [[1]] (also, my bad, my functions are not linear like the ones in the example I set).

Comment: Also, the Outer runs the function s for different combinations of k, m and t. There, I don't understand the division by 2, 3 and 4, and I do not get the meaning of the structure of the list. If it is possible, I would like to get a table giving me the final solution together with the values of the parameters that generate that solution.

Comment: If your equations are not linear there will be multiple solutions.  `[[1]]` picks the first one, but you might not desire that 'feature' for a nonlinear problem.  `Solve` produces a set of `Rule`s `{x -> something, y-> somethingElse}`; `{x,y} /. Solve[...]` says: give me the _values_ of the rules, not the rules themselves.

My function `s` does not solve the problem repeatedly; it solves it once for generic k, m, and t, and then plugs those values in when provided.  If, in your 'real' example you can't get an exact solution, you probably want `s[k, m, t]:=NSolve[...]`

Comment: `Outer` applies `s` to a bunch of different choices for k, m, and t; [the documentation is good](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html).  If you want to see the input values, you can change `s` to `List`.  `Outer[List, (*k:*)Subdivide[0, 1, 2],(*m:*)Subdivide[0, 1, 3],(*t:*) Subdivide[0, 1, 4]]` which produces a list of lists with the same `Dimensions`.  If you just want a simple list, `Flatten`ing the `Table` approach is probably easier, if you're new to Mathematica.  You can do eg. `Table[{k,m,t,s[k,m,t]}, ...]`.

Comment: Also, two comments ago, I meant `s[k_, m_, t_]:=NSolve[...]`; the underscores matter :P

Comment: As to `Subdivide`:  I just wanted something that gave a short list of values for each parameter.  You can put in arbitrary lists, `Range`s, and other things.

Comment: Wow, you are very good at explaining stuff, thank a lot.
I have almost understood everything, just I do not get the part about flattening the table (I have checked the documentation, but I am not sure how I should use it).

Comment: If you let `example = Table[ {x,y}, {k,0,3}, {m,0,4},{t,0,5}]`, for example, you don't just get a single list, but you get a list of lists of lists, `Dimensions[example] == {4,5,6,2}`.  If you want just a single list you want to `Flatten`.  But you don't want to `Flatten` _all the way_ because you still want `{x,y}` pairs.  If you `Flatten[example, 2]` you will get something with `Dimensions` `{120,2}`, and 120=4*5*6, so now that big list of lists of lists is unraveled into one giant list.

Comment: Really, you saved my life and you made me improving my knowledge about this software a lot! Thank you <3

Comment: Sure thing!  You'll find this community very welcoming and helpful!